# Aligning equations after some text

Tags: align

I'm wondering how to align equations after text, such as this:

```
But x + y = 2
        y = 2 - x
          = 2 - 3
          = -1
```

The only way I can see myself doing this is putting the text inside the align environment like this:

```
\begin{align*}
\text{But } x + y &= 2 \\
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1
\end{align*}
```

This doesn't seem very "clean" in my opinion. Is there a better option?

Comment: Where `But` should be? On left margin? What about text around the equations?

Comment: It should be on the "left side" of the align environment. Essentially I just want the align environment to be flush with the left margin, and then squeeze the `But` text into between the left margin and the align environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think of the word as a label in the alignment what you suggest is OK, but if you think of the math as part of the surrounding sentence a more natural markup might be `aligned`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

zzzz
\begin{align*}
\text{But } x + y &= 2 \\
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1
\end{align*}



zzzz But $\begin{aligned}[t]
x + y &= 2 \\
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following MWE presents a solution that uses the `flalign` environment and left aligns it with the left margin of the text, while keeping the centered alignment of `align` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{But } x + y &= 2 \\
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1 
\end{align*}

\begin{flalign*}
\text{But } x + y &= 2 \\ 
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1 &\\
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

The starred version suppresses numbering of all lines similar to the starred version of `align`. Please note that, in contrast to `aling`, you seem to need `&\\` at the end of the last line, otherwise the environment is horizontally centered.

Comment: But the equations should be in math mode. Compare your `-1` with the one in math mode (eg. $-1$ or inside `align`).

Comment: Well remembered. I think `flalign` is what he wants. Good!

Comment: In my opinion you could edit and delete about `tabbing`. It is not good for this.

Comment: @Sigur: You are right. I have edited my anser accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think your proposed solution is quite nice. Just one improvement to keep the same horizontal alignment for `align` environment. See the use of `\llap{}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align*}
\text{But } x + y &= 2 \\
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1
\end{align*}
%
\begin{align*}
\llap{But } x + y &= 2 \\
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1
\end{align*}
%
\begin{align*}
x + y &= 2 \\
y &= 2 - x \\
&= 2 - 3 \\
&= -1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This may not have been very clear in the post, but I also wanted the `align` environment to sit flush with the left margin of the page.

Comment: @SkeletonBow that's a global setting: `fleqn` option